# how to set expression variable in query select oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have Oracle SQL like these :

```
SELECT  
z."date", z.id_outlet as idOutlet, z.name as outletName, z.matClass, z.targetBulanan, z.targetBulanan/totalVisit as targetAwal,
z.actual,rownumber = tartot + rownumber as targetTotal
                FROM (SELECT 
                b.visit_date as "date", a.id_outlet, max(o.name) as name, max(a.target_sales) as targetBulanan, a.id_material_class as matClass, 
                max(x.totalVisit) as totalVisit, NVL(SUM(d.billing_value),0) as actual 
                FROM (
                select * from target_bulanan 
                where deleted = 0 and enabled = 1 and id_salesman = :id_salesman AND id_material_class like :id_material_class AND id_outlet like :id_outlet AND month = TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(current_date,'mm')) and year = to_number(TO_CHAR(current_date,'YYYY')) 
                ) a 
                INNER JOIN outlet o ON o.id_outlet = a.id_outlet 
                LEFT JOIN visit_plan b ON b.deleted = 0 and a.id_salesman = b.id_salesman AND a.month =  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(b.visit_date,'mm')) AND a.year = to_number(TO_CHAR(b.visit_date,'yyyy')) AND a.id_outlet = b.id_outlet 
                LEFT JOIN so_header c ON SUBSTR(c.id_to,'0',1) = 'TO' AND  a.id_salesman = c.id_salesman AND a.id_outlet = c.id_outlet 
                LEFT JOIN assign_billing d ON c.no_so_sap = d.no_so_sap AND d.billing_date = b.visit_date AND a.id_material_class = (SELECT id_material_class FROM material WHERE id = d.id_material) 
                LEFt JOIN (SELECT id_salesman, to_char(visit_date,'mm') as month, to_char(visit_date,'yyyy') as year, id_outlet, COUNT(*) as totalVisit  FROM visit_plan 
                WHERE deleted = 0 
                group by id_salesman, id_outlet,to_char(visit_date,'mm'), to_char(visit_date,'yyyy')) x on 
                x.id_salesman = a.id_salesman AND x.month =  a.month AND x.year = a.year AND x.id_outlet = a.id_outlet
                GROUP BY b.visit_date, a.id_outlet, a.id_material_class) z 
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 as rownumber FROM DUAL ) r
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 as tartot FROM DUAL ) t
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT '' as mat FROM DUAL ) m
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT '' as outlet FROM DUAL ) o
                ORDER by outletName, z.matClass, z."date"
```

I want value of rownumber is formula in my select query but the result is error with this message

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
>   00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Anyone can help me ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

THIS ADDRESSES THE ORIGINAL QUESTION.

You may have multiple problems in your query.  After all, the best way to debug and to write queries is to start simple and gradually add complexity.

But, you do have an obvious error.  In your outermost `select`:

```
SELECT z."date", z.id_outlet as idOutlet, z.name as outletName, 
       z.matClass, z.targetBulanan, z.targetBulanan/totalVisit as targetAwal,
       z.actual,
       rownumber = rownumber + 1 as row_number
```

The `=` is not Oracle syntax -- it looks like a SQL Server extension for naming a column or a MySQL use of variables.

I suspect that you want to enumerate the rows.  If so, one syntax is `row_number()`:

```
SELECT z."date", z.id_outlet as idOutlet, z.name as outletName, 
       z.matClass, z.targetBulanan, z.targetBulanan/totalVisit as targetAwal,
       z.actual,
       row_number() over (order by outletName, z.matClass, z."date") as row_number
```

In Oracle, you could also do:

```
       rownum as row_number
```

Comment: yess ,, but rownumber is variable that i create for increament like i replace it to variable x = x+2 rownumber that i mean not the function in oracle but the variable that i create from the cross join

Answer (score 0):

Just for enumeration - 
replace the line

```
rownumber = rownumber + 1 AS row_number
```

with this

```
rownum AS row_number
```

rownum is an Oracle inbuilt function that enumerates each record of the result set and with auto increments

As mentioned by [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) in his answer, there are further problems in your query.

At the first look (without executing it), I could list the problematic lines -

```
AND month = TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(current_date,'mm')) 
AND year = to_number(TO_CHAR(current_date,'YYYY'))
```

Instead of current_date use sysdate

```
LEFT JOIN so_header c ON SUBSTR(c.id_to,'0',1) = 'TO'
```

I guess, you meant to do this -

```
LEFT JOIN so_header c ON SUBSTR(c.id_to,0,2) = 'TO'
```

i.e. substring from index 0 upto 2 characters

Plus, no need of those cross joins

Comment: yess ,, but rownumber is variable that i create for increament like i replace it to variable x = x+2 rownumber that i mean not the function in oracle but the variable that i create from the cross join